# Какой язык веб-программирования выбрать?

Tags: веб-программирование

прочитал в интернете (javascript,typescript )
самые популярные клиентские языки
из серверных php,python...
моя цель- научиться создавать сайты;
 Я не знаю какие языки актуальны в наше время для этой цели(html и css я про них знаю).Выбрать javascript  или python или вообще несколько языков .Пожалуйста помогите с выбором.

Comment: не ставьте минусы от них не холодно, не жарко.

Comment: Задавайте нормальные вопросы -- не будет минусов.

Answer (score 1):

Начните с изучения языков исполняющихся на клиентской стороне.
`HTML+CSS+JAVASCRIPT`.Как минимум основы чтобы понять как работает отображение контента.
Дальше плавно переходите к `PYTHON/PHP` для того чтобы доставать контент для этого *"отображения"*.Чтобы упростить работу после изучения хотя бы основ можете опробовать фреймворки

Но,если задача просто создать контентный сайт,то используйте готовые CMS вроде `WORDPRESS`,`DLE`.Статей много, сами поймете что вам нужно.

Скажу только к этому , что языки необходимо знать хотя бы на базе для маленьких правок,понимания и так далее.

P.s - вам ставят минусы потому что вы задаёте не очень правильный и много раз повторяющийся вопрос.Уже куча раз его обсуждали поэтому данный вопрос могут закрыть и указать копию / попросить изучить `GOOGLE`